# Array list display online one result from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I wrote this code and it works:

```
function getJsonResult(retrieve) {
  var result = retrieve.results;     
  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    responseJson.push({ id: result[i].id, title: result[i].title });
    var search = '<a id="' + result[i].id + '">' + result[i].title + '</a><br/>';
    document.write(search);
  } 
}
```

When I tried to display the results in a div, I change the last line with:

```
$("#divId").html(search);
```

But it only displays the first result. How can I make the whole list appear?

Comment: `html()` overwrites the existing content. Use `append()` instead.

Comment: I don't believe you when you say it shows the first result. It should show the *last* result.

Comment: Concatenate all the HTML into a string in the loop, then call `.html()` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happened because you're overriding the `search` variable in every iteration :

```
var search = '<a id="' + result[i].id + '">' + result[i].title + '</a><br/>';
```

You need to declare the `search` variable outside of the loop then append the string in every iteration like :

```
function getJsonResult(retrieve) {
  var result = retrieve.results;  
  var search = "";
  ___________^^^^
  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    responseJson.push({ id: result[i].id, title: result[i].title });
    var search += '<a id="' + result[i].id + '">' + result[i].title + '</a><br/>';
    ___________^^
    document.write(search);
  } 
}
```

Then finally you could put your variable content to the div :

```
$("#divId").html(search);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#divId').append(search);
```

This appends the

element included in search to the div element.